# Writing "raw binary" string with fileWriter

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-chrome-app, arraybuffer

I would like to write a binary string (like the output of XMLHttpRequest when 'text/plain; charset=x-user-defined' is used) to the disk using fileWriter API.
Currently I am converting my "raw string" to Uint8Array array then write the file as a blob, `let blob = new Blob([uarr], {type: 'application/octet-stream'}); fileWriter.write(blob);`.

I was wondering if it would be possible to write the "raw binary" string directly to the file. Perhaps by using TextEncoder API.

I am asking this because Cordova does not support blob writing at least on Android and to me conversion from "raw string" to Uint8Array array seems to be inefficient

```
  let uarr = new Uint8Array(content.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    uarr[i] = content.charCodeAt(i);
  }
```

Comment: Why can't you set `xhr.responseType="arraybuffer"` and make an Uint8array directly from the response like `var uarr=new Uint8Array(xhr.response)` ?

Comment: This could solve the loop problem, however, I need to the binary string as I am altering the string upon arrival. And note that still array buffer cannot be fed to the `fileWriter.write` on Cordova.